# SELECT a string formatted array by row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

For instance I have a string parameter `@p_colors` with a value like:

`'yellow','blue','red'`

which is passed into a stored procedure. And when I try to select it like this:

```
EXECUTE(CONCAT('SELECT ', @p_colors));
```

The result is the values are selected by columns.

```
No column name | No column name | No column name
------------------------------------------------
Yellow         | Blue           | Red
```

How will I do it if I want to display them by row like this:

```
No column name |
----------------
Yellow         |
----------------
Blue           |
----------------
Red            |
----------------
```

using only the string formatted parameter. Is there any way in SQL to make this?

**EDIT:**

The actual result will be inserted into a temp table so the actual code is :

```
EXECUTE('INSERT INTO #colors(color) SELECT ', @p_colors);
```

Comment: @zoharpeled The question seems to be different?

Comment: Downvote reason: not even minimal reaserch. a simple search for "split strings sql server" would give you 478,000 on google, and 841,000 on Bing.

Comment: @Neer how is it different? It's a simple string split question.

Comment: As a parameter and want to run it

Comment: @NEER I'm not following. Why is splitting a hard coded string should be different then splitting a string inside a parameter? It's the same thing

Comment: I do not agree with you.

Comment: That I understand, what I don't understand is **why**. You can vote to reopen, but if you can provide a good reason why it's different then any other string splitting scenario I'll be happy to revoke my close vote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142955/discussion-between-neer-and-zohar-peled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can as the below:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES('yellow'), ('blue'), ('red')) t(c)
```

Update:

```
DECLARE @Param NVARCHAR(MAX) = '''yellow'', ''red'', ''blue'''
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @Query = 'SELECT * FROM (VALUES(' + REPLACE(@Param, ''',', '''),(') + ')) t(c)'
--SELECT @Query
EXEC sp_executesql  @Query
```

Comment: In this solution I think I have to make my string to be formatted like this `('yellow'),('blue'),('red')`. How can I make it using only `'yellow', 'red', 'blue'`

Comment: @RedMagda Answer updated.

Comment: The updated solution works well for me, very simple yet effective